# node.js refactoring: How to pass object-pointer (here: a socket)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, refactoring

## Goal

Avoiding "callback hell" in node.js.

## Problem

The socket-object is not available anymore after refactoring.
How can it be passed to the function?

## Before refactoring

### server.js

```
var  ActiveSession = require('./session-model');

// ...

socket.on("c2s_logout", function (message) {
    ActiveSession.remove({ sessionid: message.sessionid } , function(err, activeSession) {
        socket.emit("s2c_logout_success");
    });
});
```

## After refactoring

### auth.js

```
var  ActiveSession = require('./session-model');
function logout(message) {
    ActiveSession.remove({ sessionid: message.sessionid } , function(err, activeSession) {
        //socket.emit("s2c_logout_success"); // THE PROBLEM
        // THIS IS NOT POSSIBLE ANYMORE AFTER REFACTORING
        // SOCKET IS NOT AVAILABLE
    });
}
module.exports.logout = logout;
```

### server.js

```
var Auth = require('./auth.js');

// ...

socket.on("c2s_logout",  Auth.logout );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken the answer from Alnitak, but corrected syntactically. 
Version is tested successfully.

## server.js

```
socket.on('c2s_logout',(message)=>{
    Auth.logout(message,(err)=>{
        if (err) {
            // logout failed
        } else {
            socket.emit('s2c_logout_success');
        }
    })
});
```

## auth.js

```
function logout(message, callback) {
    ActiveSession.remove({sessionid: message.sessionid}, (err, activeSession) => 
        callback(err)
    )
}
```

Comment: I've fixed the typo now - there was no need to supply a "new" answer that just corrects it

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the socket to the logout function.

auth.js

```
var  ActiveSession = require('./session-model');
function logout(message, socket) {
    ActiveSession.remove({ sessionid: message.sessionid } , function(err, activeSession) {
        socket.emit("s2c_logout_success"); // NO PROBLEM

    });
}
module.exports.logout = logout;
```

server.js

```
var Auth = require('./auth.js');

// ...

socket.on("c2s_logout", function(message){  Auth.logout(message, socket); });
```

Comment: this would be bad design - the logout function shouldn't be aware of the socket

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that it's even appropriate to decouple the `socket` and the `ActiveSession` object, you would need to pass a callback to the `logout` function, e.g.:

```
function logout(message, callback) {
    ActiveSession.remove({ sessionid: message.sessionid },
        (err, activeSession) => callback(err)
    );
}
```

[I've omitted the `activeSession` variable from the parameters passed back on the basis that this shouldn't be exposed to the upper layers of the code]

and then in use:

```
socket.on('c2s_logout', () => {
     Auth.logout(err => {
         if (err) {
             ...
         } else {
             socket.emit('s2c_logout_success');
         }
     });
});
```

This is *separation of responsibility* - your `Auth` module shouldn't know anything about the `socket` nor which messages are sent over it.

The code looks slightly longer now because there's an error handling branch.

Comment: function logout(message, callback) {
 ActiveSession.remove({sessionid: message.sessionid}, (err, activeSession) => 
  callback(err)
 )
}